# Executing wkhtmltopdf from PHP fails

Tags: php, exec, wkhtmltopdf

There have been a few topics similar to mine, but they did not help me. Maybe something new will come up.

Problem: I can't execute wkhtmltopdf form PHP.
My basic code is: 
`exec('wkhtmltopdf http://somesite.com /home/user/file.pdf');`

Now a few things I already checked:

- the same command works when executed from console
- safe_mode is disabled - I can execute commands in PHP, for example `exec('ls');` works fine
- path to wkhtmltopdf can be found and I can run the program itself, for example `exec('wkhtmltopdf -V');` works fine and outputs versioning info
- the output path is writable, it has 777 permissions and `exec('wkhtmltopdf -V > /home/user/file.pdf');` works fine, creates the file and puts versioning info inside
- executing from PHP has internet access, for exemple `exec('wget -O /home/user/file.pdf http://somesite.com')` works fine, retrieves the site source and puts it into the file
- replacing exec with passthru, shell_exec etc. makes no difference

Concluding:
I can execute wkhtmltopdf, I can access internet, I can write the specific file, but a correct conversion command fails and returns status 1.

I use the latest Ubuntu, PHP Version is 5.3.10-1ubuntu3, wkhtmltopdf version is 0.9.9.
I tried it also on some other machine with the same retults.

Any (just ANY) ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Problem solved. It was a common issue which happens when you install wkhtmltopdf via apt-get. I had to remove it and download directly from code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf. Now it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `2>&1` to the end of your command to understand the exact error.

`exec('wkhtmltopdf http://somesite.com /home/user/file.pdf 2>&1');`

This way it will tell you the error when running this under Apache. Once you know what's wrong, it is easier to address. I had a [similar problem before with ImageMagick](http://blog.dakdad.com/post/5478692690/php-imagemagick-terminal)

Comment: Man, you saved my life!
Your idea worked and showed me an error "cannot connect to X server".
Then it was easy to find that it is a common problem when you install wkhtmltopdf via apt-get. I had to remove it and download directly from http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/. Now it works :) Thanks so much!