# exec & shell_exec not working with vlc -I rc command

Tags: php, shell, drupal, command-line, vlc

I wish to do recording of the live http streaming on the server side.
I am able to do the recording on server via ssh and then writting the vlc -I rc command 
But when i write the same command in the exec function like :-
exec("vlc -I rc REST_OF_THE_COMMAND"); IT doesnt works , But 
exec("ls -l") & exec("pwd") works

So my problem is that vlc command line is not working with the exec or shell_exec function.

Comment: typing vlc in command line launches the vlc player but in this case even the code shell_exec("vlc") is not working. I am running the php on my localhost

Answer (score 1):

Please check this answer (relates to executing commands from PHP). Once you know the exact problem, then it is easier to find a solution.

[Executing wkhtmltopdf from PHP fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631605/executing-wkhtmltopdf-from-php-fails/10670682#10670682)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. if i type vlc in command line then the vlc player is launched and now if i type $output = shell_exec("vlc 2>&1");  
       print_r(''.$output);  i get sh: vlc command not found

Comment: Well, that's your problem - vlc is not in the path as far as apache is concerned. You need update the apache PATH to include the dir where vlc executable is located

Comment: Thanks for the tip man. Where shall i update the apache PATH ? is it in httpd-vhosts.conf file>>?

Comment: Depends on your system configuration. Here is one that's on Mac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837697/how-do-i-add-paths-to-the-apache-path-variable